# Magento CE 1.9.1 permission to access scss files denied (dev environment using MAMP)

Tags: permissions, access, scss, sass

I'be been trying to solve this for hours, to no avail :( I would like to inspect (**in the browser**) the RWD sass rules based on the generated map files, but access is denied to all files in the scss directory. Read/write privileges are OK and I've been tinkering with .htaccess rules as well, but so far no luck.

What else should I check?
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `scss` directory lives an `.htaccess` file which contains:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Remove it or comment it out and everything is fine.